# How to change JPA connection on the fly

Tags: java, jpa, singleton, entitymanager

I'm using JPA for a desktop software. The end user needed a frame to change the Database connection dynamically (on the fly) by changing the persistance.xml data. I've tried using below code (which I found here) and modified but so far unsuccessful in changing the database connection.

```
EntityManagerFactory managerFactory = EntityManagerSingleton.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory();
managerFactory = null;
Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName+"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser);
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPwd);
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

managerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistance Unit Name", persistenceMap);
manager = managerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

I'm using a singleton class to get the entity manager factory so it will create only one connection to the database and only one Entity manager factory. Above **managerFactory**
is the returned value from the singleton class. So can anyone tell me what I was doing wrong or a better way to do this?

Comment: and EMF corresponds to a database. Once created, that is it.

Comment: It's because I've made it as a singleton object? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583881/changing-persistence-unit-dynamically-jpa) This question shows how to do it, but for that moment only. Are you suggesting me to not to use singleton?

Comment: I'm not suggested anything. I'm saying an EMF corresponds to a database; a JPA provider will create a connection pool at startup of the EMF. If you want to change the pool then you close the EMF and create a new one ... that is the portable way

Comment: Thanks man, that worked flawlessly. I've changed `managerFactory = null; ` to `managerFactory.close();`