# How to override the persistent xml file in junit class which will be used in other java class?

Tags: jpa, junit4, persistence.xml

I have a junit test class in which I have to specify the new persistent unit name suppose say "B" with properties connecting to the DB. From this test class I am invoking a JPA REST service which in turn calls a business logic java class. In this business logic class, I have written entitymanager with the persistent xml unit suppose say "A".

Question here is how can I specify the persistent unit B in junit test class so that the business class uses persistent unit B instead of A?

Comment: persistence-unit is specified in a file persistence.xml NOT in a class. Define better what you mean

Comment: We can specify a new persistence unit in class like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18733128

I have checked this but did not work for me. Please understand what is being asked in question.

Comment: That is not a "new persistence unit". That is the SAME persistence unit with some extra properties that override those specified in the persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your

> src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

with

> src\test\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml

Comment: I have seen this but the problem is that my junit class takes src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml instead of src\test\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml, I think because I need to specify this path somewhere.

Comment: Which framework do you use for JPA Unit Tests? Only junit?